# How to run only xUnit tests with specific name through console/powershell?

Tags: powershell, xunit, xunit.net

I am currently running tests through Visual Studio interface, and that provides easy option to run only certain test. I want to do same, but through console / powershell.

Right now if I do `dotnet test` that will run all discovered tests. Is it possible to do something similar like `dotnet test MyTest` which would only run specific test?

Answer (score 1):

Command `dotnet test` has switch `--filter` that allows you to filter tests and get only those that you want to run. So you can do:

```
dotnet test -t
```

To see full list of tests available, and then in order to just run specific ones you can do:

```
dotnet test --filter "FullyQualifiedName~ShouldInterconnect"
```

Which will execute only the tests containing `ShouldInterconnect` in the name.